# how to select rows of a table in 3th multiply order in sql like 3,6,9 etc

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

My table consists of 1024 rows and two columns.
I want to select and display rows like 3,4,6,etc..
Is it possible in sql query. 
If possible what is the code for that..

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres or MySQL? You added a tag for each one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a relational database there is no concept of the "3rd" or "6th" row *unless* you can define a sort order.

Assuming you do have a column by which you can order the result in order to define a row as "3rd", or "4th", the following will work with Postgres:

```
select *
from (
  select col1, col2, col3, 
         row_number() over (order by your_sort_column) as rn
  from your_table
) t 
where rn in (3,4,6);
```

Where `your_sort_column` is the one that defines the order or rows. This could be an incremental id or a timestamp column that stores the time of insert or update of the row.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL it can be accomplished as follows:

```
SELECT * from 
(SELECT (@row := @row + 1) num, tab.* FROM your_table, (SELECT @row := 0) r
ORDER by your_sort_column) t
WHERE (num % 3) = 0
```

We have used a MODULO operator to get row which is at multiple of 3.

See it working at SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/192b0/4

In PostgreSQL it can be accomplished as follows:

```
select *
from (
  select *, row_number() over (order by your_sort_column) as rn
  from your_table
) t 
where (rn % 3)=0 ;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cc649/5